# Error in Page Object Model, Attribute value must be constant

Tags: java, appium

i want to get element but the element its for calendar and the id related to number and i want to random number from 1 to 28:
example element:

calendarCell1

calendarCell2

so here my code

```
public static final Random rand = new Random();
public static final Integer min =1;
public static final Integer max =28;
public static final Integer value = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
public static final String number = Integer.toString(value);
public static final String calendar = “calendarCell”+number+;

@iOSFindBy (xpath = " //*[contains(text()='"+calendar+"']")
IOSElement randomCalendar;
```

but i getting error Attribute value must be constant in iosfindby line
any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works -

```
public static final Random rand = new Random();
public static final Integer min =1;
public static final Integer max =28;
public static final Integer value = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
public static final String number = Integer.toString(value);
public static final String calendar = “calendarCell”+number+;
public static final String XPATH = " //*[contains(text()='"+calendar+"']";

@iOSFindBy (xpath = XPATH)
IOSElement randomCalendar;
```

Comment: Hi thx for answering but still get error attribute value must be constant